# Avoiding strings and hardcoded function names – advantages?

Tags: javascript

I recently came across a JavaScript script, in which the author seemed to try to avoid strings inside his code and assigned everything to a variable.

So instead of

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => { /*whatever*/ });
```

he would write

```
var doc = document;
var click = 'click';
var EventListener = 'EventListener';
var addEventListener = `add${EventListener}`;
doc[addEventListener](click, (e) => { /*whatever*/ });
```

While caching `document` into a variable can be regarded a micro optimization, I am really wondering if there is any other benefit of this practice in general - testability, speed, maintenance, anything?

Legacy IE `attachEvent` should be pretty much dead, so being able to quickly make the script only run in these environments can hardly be regarded an advantage I suppose.

Comment: Maybe he was afraid of loosing his job and wrote code that can only be maintained by him... :-)

Comment: That seems bizarre to me-- while it is definitely advisable to avoid [magic strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string), and it is good to store strings in a variable where the string may change but the semantic `var` name would be constant, I can't imagine doing front end web work in which `click` would be changing, or the `document` would somehow be a different object...

Comment: A copyright trap, maybe?

Comment: in php, you often have to break long chains into separate lines, habit?

Comment: obfuscation and minification

Comment: Depending on his IDE, he might get autocomplete for variables but not properties - also, warnings on misspelled ones.

Answer (score 1):

The example you give looks pretty strange, and I can't imagine any "good practice" reason for most of those moves.  My first guess was that it's the work of someone who wasn't sure what they were doing, although it's odd that they'd also be using ECMAScript 6 syntax.

Another possibility is that this is generated code (e.g. the output of some kind of visual programming tool, or a de-minifier).  In that situation it's common to see this sort of excessive factoring because the code is generated from templates that are conservatively written to guard against errors; I'm thinking of the way preprocessor macros in C make liberal use of parentheses.

Sometimes variable declarations are written in a way that makes clear (to the compiler and/or the reader) what type of data the variable holds.  For instance, asm.js code uses unnecessary-looking variable declarations as a trick to implement strongly-typed variables on top of regular JS.  And sometimes declarations are written as a form of documentation (if you see `var foo = Math.PI * 0`, that's probably there to tell *you* that `foo` is an angle in radians, since otherwise the author would have just written `var foo = 0.0`).  But that still wouldn't explain something like `var click='click'`.